# Create an array of JSON within a JSON in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have 2 tables as below and I am currently writing a function that returns a JSON based on these tables. Need help in querying this.

```
 TABLE1
 Id    ReqMode    RespMode    Count    TabName   
 1001  R          T           5000     TAB3
 1002  R          Y           10000    TAB4
 1003  R          T           3000     TAB6
 1004  R          T           5000     TAB5
 1005  R          Y           6000     TAB2


 TABLE2
 TabName  CMeth  CDate  UMeth  UDate DMeth  DDate  ParentTab  
 TAB1     F      A1     F      L1    C
 TAB2     P             C            C             TAB1
 TAB3     P             C            C             TAB2
 TAB4     F      B5     C            C                
 TAB5     P             C            C             TAB4
 TAB6     C             C            C
```

JSON Format :

```
{  
   "d":{  
      "Id":"1001",
      "ReqMode":"R",
      "RespMode":"T",
      "Count":5000,
      "TabName":"TAB3",
      "DELTA":[  
         {  
            "Tabname":"TAB3",
            "CMeth":"P",
            "CDate":"",
            "UMeth":"C",
            "UDate":"",
            "DMeth":"C",
            "DDate":"",
            "ParentTab":"TAB2"
         },
         {  
            "Tabname":"TAB2",
            "CMeth":"P",
            "CDate":"",
            "UMeth":"C",
            "UDate":"",
            "DMeth":"C",
            "DDate":"",
            "ParentTab":"TAB1"
         },
         {  
            "Tabname":"TAB1",
            "CMeth":"F",
            "CDate":"A1",
            "UMeth":"F",
            "UDate":"L1",
            "DMeth":"",
            "DDate":"C",
            "ParentTab":""
         }
      ],
      "MDATA":[ ]
   }
}
```

Explanation :
If I am requesting for 'TAB3' , then I need to pull a record from TABLE1 where TabName is TAB3. Based on this table name, I check for its values in TABLE2.
My methods have values P(Parent),C(Change),F(Field)

The logic behind getting 3 rows here in my DELTA part of JSON is  :
For TabName TAB3, if P is present in any of the Methods in TABLE2,then pick the ParentTab value and comapare it against TabName in TABLE2 and get its details. This is a recursive loop until we come across C or F in any of the Methods.

I am currently lost in how to create a recursive loop based on the values. My query so far :

```
select Id AS 'd.Id', ReqMode AS 'd.ReqMode' ,RespMode AS 'd.RespMode',Count AS 'd.Count',TabName AS 'd.TabName'
,JSON_QUERY('[]') 'd.DELTA',JSON_QUERY('[]') 'd.MDATA'
FROM TABLE1 
FOR JSON PATH
```

Need help in creating DELTA part of my JSON which will depend on the TabName I pass as an input to the function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those that would like some useful sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bef1009e1b412f68f6446fa82f47a69e)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little late, but this should give you what you're looking for. It is important to note recursive cte's have a default limit of 100, but you can use the MAXRECURSION option to configure a reasonable limit for your situation.

```
declare @id int = 1001
declare @tab varchar(100) = (select tabName from Table1 where id = @id);

with delta as (
    select tabname,cmeth,isnull(cdate,'') as cdate
      ,umeth,isnull(udate,'') as udate
      ,dmeth,isnull(ddate,'') as ddate
      ,isnull(parenttab,'') as parenttab 
    from dbo.Table2 
    where tabname = @tab
    union all
    select t.tabname,t.cmeth,isnull(t.cdate,'') as cdate
      ,t.umeth,isnull(t.udate,'') as udate
      ,t.dmeth,isnull(t.ddate,'') as ddate
      ,isnull(t.parenttab,'') as parenttab  
    from dbo.Table2 t 
      inner join delta d on t.tabname = d.parenttab
)
SELECT ID as 'd.id'
    ,ReqMode as 'd.reqmode'
    ,RespMode as 'd.respmode'
    ,[Count] as 'd.count'
    ,TabName as 'd.tabname'
    ,json_query((select distinct * from delta for json path)) as delta
    ,json_query('[]') as mdata
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
WHERE ID = @id
FOR JSON PATH;
go
```